# How can i completely exit a modal after i close it

Tags: javascript, html

I have this model in my page which is working fine but when i close it the url still has its name like #modalname.
Here is my code:

```
<script>

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("adm");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
} 

</script>
```

Here is html code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
              <center>
                <label style="font-size: 25px; color:#2193b0;"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>Enter Admin Password to access Admin Section</label>
              <br><br>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="" class="input-text"  autocomplete="off" style="width:500px;height: 50px;">
            <br>
            <a href="./admin/index.php" onclick="javascript:return validatePass()"><button class="button" name="check"><span>GO</span></button></a>
            <br></center>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is how i access the modal:

```
<li id="adm"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i><a href="#myModal">Admin</a></li>
```

This is how my url looks after i close it:

```
http://localhost/project/index.php#myModal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why you have to use <a href="#myModal> to open modal, just replace it by button:

```
<li id="adm"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i><button>Admin</button></li>
```

If you dont want to use button because it's default style, you can try with `<span>` tag:

```
<li id="adm"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i><span style="cursor:pointer">Admin</span></li>
```

For `<a>` tag:

```
<li id="adm"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i><a role="button">Admin</a></li>
```

Comment: this line is in my navbar which has some styles set . thts why i have used <a> tag to make it look like other elements there.

Comment: using span messed up the style but it atleast works better than using <a> tag in close. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice to have a separate functions to open and close the modal,

```
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

So your code with all of the above combined should be smth like this:

```
// This removes hash
function removeHash() { 
  history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
}
    
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
  removeHash();
}

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById('adm');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

btn.onclick = openModal;    
span.onclick = closeModal;    
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    closeModal();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this leaves a # in the url though.

Comment: and do you need that #myModal in the url at all?

Comment: i want it to return to original url when i close it.

Comment: http://localhost/project/index.php  This is before i click the modal

Comment: idk whose answer to accept urs or @btb both of your answers worked for me. btb's answer was simpler. so i selected that as accepted answer.

Comment: @USer12345 that's ok.
you may need that hash thing in url to detect if you need to display modal at page load, then my answer fit this with some improvements, if you don't need that ability, then you don't need any hash in url so btb's answer would be better.

Comment: i have set display:none in stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<a href=""></a>` to the close button

Comment: this makes my page reload after i close it. Can we do it in some other way without have to reload.